# Gettng error while creating DSE Graph -"Host did not respond in a timely fashion"

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup, datastax-enterprise-graph

We are using DataStax Enterprise version 5.0.1 and are facing issue while creating the graph from the Gremlin Console.

Here are the details of the error that I am getting:

```
adminuser@dc0vm1:~$ dse gremlin-console
     \,,,/
     (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
==>Configured 13.82.30.252/13.82.30.252:8182
gremlin> :> 1+1
Host did not respond in a timely fashion - check the server status and submit again.
gremlin> :> system.graph('food').create()
Host did not respond in a timely fashion - check the server status and submit again.
```

I changed the **Remote.yaml** file settings from [locahost] to
hosts: [13.82.30.252].

**I ran the nodetool command** to check if the server is running properly:

```
adminuser@dc0vm1:~$ nodetool status

Datacenter: dc0

Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack

UN  13.82.25.134  168.92 KB  64           ?       d7a98eed-9b15-42ee-bc5c-f406e98fd6fc  FD2

UN  13.82.25.152  189.17 KB  64           ?       7ffa11ea-8607-4bdb-903b-2ee3baeacae8  FD0

UN  13.82.30.252  150.6 KB   64           ?       a57f6cd8-5466-480e-b919-329c36fbfd28  FD1
```

**The cassandra.yaml has the following entries related to the host:**

```
 broadcast_rpc_address: 13.82.30.252

 rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
```

*Could you please let me know what configuration I am missing here?*

Comment: How did you set up the cluster.  Was it using LCM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that by default the DSE Graph service is not enabled so you need to edit the file "dse" to enable it -

```
sudo vim /etc/default/dse
```

Make sure that the following parameter is set to 1 –

```
# Enable the DSE Graph service on this node
GRAPH_ENABLED=1
```

Restart the DSE service -

```
sudo service dse stop
sudo service dse start
```

Now Gremlin Console is able to connect and create the Graph.